# Append domain to container hostnames in a Kubernetes StatefulSet

Tags: kubernetes, hostname, containers

I have created a Kubernetes StatefulSet. There are three pods in the StatefulSet with names `mysql-0`, `mysql-1`, and `mysql-2` each with a single container.

If I "log" onto the container in pod `mysql-1` and type `hostname` I get the response `mysql-1`. However, what I *want* is for the container to think its hostname is `mysql-1.example.com`. In other words, force the hostname to have the domain appended.

How do I get the StatefulSet to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

As per http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hostname.7.html:

> Valid characters for hostnames are ASCII(7) letters
>          from a to z, the digits from 0 to 9, and the hyphen (-).  A hostname
>          may not start with a hyphen.

Above is also true for subdomains. Here is a regex used for validation: `[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?`

However, you can use `hostname:` and `subdomain:` fields in a pod definition, as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-hostname-and-subdomain-fields)

A ReplicaSet with above fields would look like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: test-replica-set
  labels:
    app: guestbook
    tier: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      hostname: my-hostname
      subdomain: my-subdomain
      containers:
      - image: busybox:1.28
        command:
          - sleep
          - "3600"
        name: busybox1
        env:
        - name: HOSTNAME
          value: "whathever.domain.com"
```

This works like so:

```
> kubectl exec test-replica-set-pz2kk -it -- hostname
my-hostname
```

You can also retrieve DNS domain name adding the `-d` option, or FQDN name using the `-f` option. This will yield K8s domain names for your pods as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).

You can also inject environmental variable to a pod and put your info there, as I did in the example above.

```
> kubectl exec test-replica-set-pz2kk -it -- sh
/ # echo $HOSTNAME
whathever.domain.com
```

Comment: Since a StatefulSet sets the hostname based on the name and a counter, how can you use the `hostname` parameter in a StatefulSet to set the internal hostname as I want?

Comment: StatefulSet sets pod name. `hostname` field sets what is being presented to container by container runtime. You can't have a hostname that includes a dot (full stop).